# enable pipelight-silverlight on Firefox 15/Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, firefox, firefox-extensions, moonlight

I have installed pipelight and enabled silverlight and flash. I can get this:

*xxx@ooo:~$ pipelight-plugin --list-enabled*

*silverlight5.1*

*flash*

And I also did:

*pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins*

But after reboot and restarting Firefox, I still couldn't see the plugin on *about:plugins*. And of course I was unable to do (see rental movies) what I need to do with silverlight. Please help! Thank you all in advance.